# cvpartition class in matlab.. c= cvpartition(n,kfold,k). what does n specify here?

Tags: matlab, data-analysis, statistics

I am actually trying to load a csv file with 1261 rows and use cvpartition class in matlab so I could collect training and testing sets for 7-models(using k='7'-fold crossvalidation).

Answer (score 0):

`n` is the number of observations that you would like to partition into training and test sets, or into folds for cross-validation. So in your case `n` would be 1261.